# Should Solidity handle the Paging in a Dapp?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

I'm using a smart contract to store a dynamic array that can grow in length. I want to render this list in the browser and would normally do that using web3 and sending a call() to get the list from the blockchain. But, since the array could potentially contain thousands of elements I wouldn't want to do this due to high gas price.

Is it appropriate to implement paging of data within the Solidity contract? If not, what other options are there?

Comment: One way or another. It's the front end UI that will know and keep track of which page the user is on at the moment. You say "But, since the array could potentially contain thousands of elements I wouldn't want to do this due to high gas price." So you want to add more for paging? Read call are free to call so...

Comment: @MadeInDreams Read calls are free that's right